# taskkill: different behaviour console vs. script

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskkill

I am writing a small shutdown script for a java application. I get the pid and then try to do the following:

```
taskkill /t /pid !pid!
```

If I am running the command from the console (typing it by hand) everything works fine. I see the shutdown routine being executed in the java console and afterwards the java console is gone. I sometimes see the windows "process not responding. kill now or wait" dialog after a few seconds but the dialog is automatically closed when the java program stops.

If i execute a bat file with the same command I immediately see the "Process not responding..." dialog. I see the console output: "process was successfully shut down" but the java console is still open. It didn't even initiate the shutdown sequence.

edit: the complete batch script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist .\lock (
set /p pid=< lock
taskkill /t /pid !pid!
)
```

Comment: You have to show us the batch script then.

Answer (score 1):

On the command line `!pid!` will normally not expanded, as delayed expansion is disabled and can only be enabled by the registry ey or with `cmd /V:on`.

So at the command line `!pid!` will stay unchanged and in the batch it will be expanded to the content of the `pid` variable.

**Edit**
As you show the *correct* command on the cmd line, the command in the batch must be wrong.

You should add an echo after the set/p line

```
Echo pid="!pid!"
```

Comment: sure. in the commandline i entered something like taskkill /pid 1234.

Comment: the two commands i run are exactly the same. Th question is: Is it possible that commands run directly from the commandline are executed a bit differently than commands run from script. Different timeout settings, another thread, ....